# Animate page based on url

Tags: jquery, html, url, jquery-animate

**how would I correctly check the current page's url and if that url is in an array animate the page?** Below is what I have so far but every page animates not just the ones in my array.

This script is loaded on every page in the footer.

I am sure this is pretty simple but I have limited JS knowledge. Thanks!

```
var pageArray = new Array( "/how-it-works.php", "/themethodology.php", "/thecommunity.php","/thetools.php" );
    var currrentPage = window.location.pathname;

    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery('currrentPage'), pageArray )){ 

    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#pageheader_cont").offset().top
        }, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"every page animates"*..? one url opens one page, right..? 0.o

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear. Every page in my navigation on click loads. but the page but then it animates when it shouldn't unless that page is in the array.

Comment: Please update the question and add the extra info there, rather than in comments. So, you have the same script across all the pages?

Comment: I updated the question to let everyone know the script is added to the footer of every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. I believe its what you want.

```
$(function(){

    var pages = new Array("how-it-works.php", "themethodology.php", "thecommunity.php","thetools.php" );

    var script = window.location.href.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]; // Get current script's name

    if (pages.indexOf(script) != -1){ 

        $('html, body').animate({

            scrollTop: $("#pageheader_cont").offset().top

        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

Comment: I am not sure why but the animation still fires every time I go to a new page no matter which page it is. Just to test I removed all the values from the array and it still animated. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right. The if condition was wrong. I've changed it and i thinks it works now.

Comment: Ah ha that did it. Thank you for your help. Was it the -1 that helped?

Comment: @Denoteone Yes. Both $.inArray() and javascript's indexOf() return -1 in case the value was not found in the array, but -1 is translated to boolean true, so that is why the code inside if was always executed